# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mmasgis]]

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, lifecycleexception

I have problem adding spring security to my spring application, I read many tutorials, but no luck ; at the end I followed this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html#registering-spring-security-with-the-war, now I have this error:

```
feb 12, 2014 2:48:38 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
Informazioni: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
feb 12, 2014 2:48:38 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
Informazioni: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 338 ms
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
Informazioni: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 138 ms
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 1203 ms
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.3.RELEASE/7.0.42.A.RELEASE
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Informazioni: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/arpho/programmi/sts/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/Catalina/localhost/mmasgis.xml
feb 12, 2014 2:48:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
Avvertenza: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MMASGIS7' did not find a matching property.
feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Informazioni: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.security.samples.config.MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer@37b87e7e]
feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Grave: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mmasgis]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.registerFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.insertSpringSecurityFilterChain(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Grave: Error deploying configuration descriptor /home/arpho/programmi/sts/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/Catalina/localhost/mmasgis.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mmasgis]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory /home/arpho/programmi/sts/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/webapps/manager
feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory /home/arpho/programmi/sts/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/webapps/ROOT
feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
feb 12, 2014 2:48:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 2240 ms
```

this is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mmasgisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mmasgisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

and my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.metmi</groupId>
    <artifactId>mmasgis</artifactId>
    <name>MMASGIS7</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version> 
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Spring Security -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
             <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
             <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
             <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using: VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.9 as server on STS

Answer (score 2):

Your web.xml contains already contains a `DelegatingFilterProxy` for the Spring Security chain. You are reregistering another one due to the use of java based configuration (the exception comes from the `SpringServletContainerInitializer`).

Remove the one from your web.xml.

Although it is strange as your web.xml specifies that your application is a 2.5 and not a 3.0 servlet api application. So it, according to the spec if I recall correctly, shouldn't even detect those classes.

Comment: No you didn't... You only removed the `filter` element also remove the `filter-mapping` element. This is also what the stacktrace is telling you.

Comment: sorry, now no filter in my web.xml, but it keep complaing about springSecurityFilterChain; http://pastebin.com/qYqisdRq

Comment: Your configuration is wrong, your filter should be defined in the root context not the one loaded by the DispatcherServlet (or configure Spring Security accordingly).